# Disable javascript function "add class on scroll" on subsite with php included header

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, include

I'm trying to disable a **JavaScript** function on certain subsites that change navigation background and text-color on the scroll.
It's defined in the header.php which is included in all sites, but at some subsites, I don't need to change the look of the navigation.

Is there a way to do this?

I also tried to add the `class` on the subsite directly by using the following code:

```
<script>
    // Selecting element
    var elem = document.getElementById("nav");     
    elem.classList.add("scrolled");  // Add a highlight class
</script>
```

But it doesn't work properly because of the other script (nav appears and disappears on scrolling).

That's the `Script`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
            var distance = 50;
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > distance) {
              $('nav').addClass('scrolled');
            }
            else {
              $('nav').removeClass('scrolled');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

`CSS`:

```
.scrolled {
  background: #fff;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}


.scrolled ul li a {
  color:#000;
}
```

and how its included:

```
<?php 
    include "css/header.inc.php"; 
?>
```

Comment: How are you identifying those “some” subsites where you don’t want the effect? I would probably just go an add a class to the html or body element of those pages, and then have the scroll script only initialize itself if that class is not present.

Comment: Basically I would like to have a code snippet on these subsites that deactivates the other one from the header, because all Elements like html, body, nav and so on till the content-section are placed in the header.php

Comment: You could just try and remove the added scroll event handler using https://api.jquery.com/unbind/ then … (Both `bind` and `unbind` are deprecated, but if it gets added using bind, then you should probably use unbind to remove it. Or replace bind with `on` to begin with, and then use its counterpart `off`.)